# IntelliJ IDEA: generating java code from wsdl using Apache CXF (WSDLToJava)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, wsdl, cxf

I'm trying to generate java code from wsdl using tools in Intellij IDEA.

1. I 've pointed path to CXF engine in `Tools->Web Services`:
   [image]
2. Added several CXF dependencies to maven

```
org.apache.cxf --> cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws
org.apache.cxf --> cxf-rt-transports-http
org.apache.cxf --> cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty
org.apache.cxf --> cxf-rt-bindings-soap
```

3. Choosing option `Tools->WebServices->Generate Java Code From Wsdl...`

   But IDEA shows the error:
   `org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava`

   [image]

Googled for CXF-plugin `cxf-codegen-plugin` which is need to be configured with wsdlPath/serviceName/sourceRoot etc.

How to generate code from wsdl with IDEA tool only once without setting plugin for maven goal? What settings are missing? Should I add extra dependency in maven pom.xml?

Comment: Do you have `lib\cxf-2.7.9.jar` file in the configured CXF location? What Java version is used for the project? Please see if it works with Java 8.

Comment: 1) there is file c:\lib\apache-cxf-2.7.9\lib\cxf-2.7.9.jar
2) java version "1.8.0_191"

Comment: Please report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA with the sample project and the logs attached (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085).